# Sharp - command failed with exit code 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharp

How to run the project when there is this error:

```
error /mnt/e/One life projects/OneLifeAdmin/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments:
Directory: /mnt/e/One life projects/OneLifeAdmin/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Please add a question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the node version. Do not delete the version that you use currently just run these commands:

sudo n i 20.3.0

yarn install